# How to enble/disable a button in TypeScript 1.5?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

Using VS 2013. After having installed TypeScript 1.5 and following the question/suggestion to upgrade:

"Your project uses a version of TypeScript older than the version currently installed with Visual Studio. You may get errors if you try to build your project. Would you like us to upgrade the TypeScriptToolsVersion in your project file so you don't see this warning again?"

I got a bunch of errors like:

Error 39    Build: Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

on statements like:

```
document.getElementById("btnExcel").disabled = false;
```

with 'disabled' curly underlined.

On https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes referring to version 1.5 it says:
"Properties on resize, disabled, uniqueID, removeNode, fireEvent, currentStyle, runtimeStyle are removed from type HTMLElement"

Now I rephrased those "erroneous" statements like this:

```
document.getElementById("btnExcel").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

which to me looks weird.

Can this be expressed more elegantly in a typesafe way in TypeScript 1.5? Can you give examples for both: enabling and disabling?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There should be a cleaner way to do this:

```
var element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("btnExcel");
element.disabled = true;
```

Or if you prefer a one liner:

```
(<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("btnExcel")).disabled = true;
```

It seems `getElementById` and the like should be a generic method and accept a type parameter. That said, a generic method wouldn't give you anything that typecasting doesn't.

Comment: In typescript I am unable to find disabled property,,,,

Comment: @Ziggler Make sure you cast the element first, or disabled won't be an option. <HTMLInputElement>

Comment: @ziggler yep, that's what the parens do, cast the element so that the property can be selected.

Comment: Thanks so much @Martin ‍

Answer (score 9):

I'm using TypeScript v 3.7.something. In here

```
(document.getElementById('button') as HTMLInputElement).disabled = false;
```

is prefered. (guided by @Martin's answer)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using "typescript": "~3.8.3" in Angular 9.
To disable a button successfully try:

```
let button = <HTMLButtonElement> document.getElementById('confirmBtn');
button.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved by using `<HTMLInputElement>`**
Just try this..

```
var previous = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('previous');

previous.disabled = true;
```